# .Net core: Rest API is getting Time out 504 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed one API in .NET Core which is consuming 4 rest service APIs. This is working fine in my local machine and the response is coming back in 6 seconds. But when I have deployed the same API and running from Postman I am getting time out error (504). Running the same API in sever via curl command
`curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/api/check`, its taking more than 6 minutes and giving 500 internal server error.

Response in local Machine:

```
status code: 200
{
    "Message": "OK",
    "Version": "1.0.0.0",
    "Path": "https://test.api.com/api/check",
    "Data": {
        "user/data": 200,
        "market/history": 200,
        "Content/Id": 200,
        "market/history/time": 200
    }
}
```

Curl command in server:

```
status code: 500
{
    "Message": "OK",
    "Version": "1.0.0.0",
    "Path": "https://test.api.com/api/check",
    "Data": {
        "user/data": 0,
        "market/history": 0,
        "Content/Id": 0,
        "market/history/time": 0
    }
}
```

Postman:

> https://test.api.com/api/check
>   status code: 504 Gateway time out

I have created singleton scope of httpclient in .net core in configureservices Method

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.api.com/")
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Key", "XYZ");
services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(client);
```

I'm not able to understand where is problem here, why its timing out when we run via postman and 500 when from server (via curl) and working fine in local machine.

Comment: Do not use a HttpClient-singleton. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: should you enable proxy for your API in the deployment server?

Comment: I have tried but result is same.

Comment: What does `/api/check` do exactly that consumes 6 full seconds on your local machine? That seems awfully long for a "check" method.

Comment: It's calling all 6 API and getting response of all 6 . After that it's passing as success if all 6 come with 200 status code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are registering `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClientFactory` is worked here. We need to add below code in `Configservices` method is `startup.cs` class

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

and add dependency for `IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory` and it works and now its taking 1573ms to respond the API.